# Bigger battery for my Toyota corolla 2015 le

Tags: battery, toyota

So I got some subs in my car they say they have the potential to pull at max 10 volts each so it'll be maybe 20. My battery is a 12volt and I'm really wanting to get a battery with more volts to make sure it doesn't crash on me but I can't find anything at all helpful please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to double check your terminology. I expect that your sub-woofers would have the ability to draw power at ten to twenty amperes, not volts. Your battery and the electrical system can provide only a limited amount of power (unknown to me) over a limited period of time.

If you want to upgrade an existing battery, consider first the physical space it occupies in the vehicle. It's not practical to shoe-horn a larger battery into the same space. I suspect that you've learned that other rolling boom-boxes add additional batteries, rather than replace one for a larger version.

Additionally, with a larger battery or a second battery, it will charge with the existing alternator at the manufacturer's maximum rate (when needed). Beyond that point, you may have to purchase a replacement alternator with a higher current capacity.

You can get away with a larger battery or a second battery without replacing the alternator if you recognize that the combination may have limitations on continuous use. It's practical to consider, for example, that your battery selection would provide sufficient power to your sound system for 4 hours continuously, but after that point would deplete the battery and eventually damage it or the alternator. Please note that the 4 hour reference is imaginary. The true duration depends on information not provided in the question, as you've not increased the amp-hour capacity of your existing system.

Comment: Also, for the relatively small subs the OP has, the usual solution is a large capacitor, not a bigger battery.